# How to use onkeypress in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to block writing special characters in input of Vue.
First, I made a function like below.

```
blockSpecialChar(e) {
      console.log(e.keyCode);
      const k = e.keyCode;
      return (
        (k > 64 && k < 91) ||
        (k > 96 && k < 123) ||
        k == 8 ||
        (k >= 48 && k <= 57)
      );
    }
```

And I connect it with the code below.

```
         <input
            type="test"
            placeholder="phone"
            v-model="pin.phoneNumber"
            v-on:keypress.prevent="blockSpecialChar(e)"
          />
```

But when I type, it says 'e is not defined'. How can I make this correctly? Thank you so much for reading.

Comment: `v-on:keypress.prevent="blockSpecialChar"` or `v-on:keypress.prevent="e => blockSpecialChar(e)"`

Comment: Thank you so much. 'e' is defined well. But the problem is that input doesn't have anything even though I type something. Is my blockspecialchar function correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont need to pass params when passing a method,

```
<input
    type="test"
    placeholder="phone"
    v-model="pin.phoneNumber"
    v-on:keypress.prevent="blockSpecialChar"
/>
```

and this code should work now

```
blockSpecialChar(e) {
      console.log(e.keyCode);
      const k = e.keyCode;
      return (
        (k > 64 && k < 91) ||
        (k > 96 && k < 123) ||
        k == 8 ||
        (k >= 48 && k <= 57)
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to pass `e` explicitly to the keypress function.

Just write:

```
<input
    type="test"
    placeholder="phone"
    v-model="pin.phoneNumber"
    v-on:keypress.prevent="blockSpecialChar"
/>
```

Because this is a callback function, `e` will be automatically initialized in your function block.